# Debugging React client on port 8001 and Node Server Port 3000 with VSCode Chrome-Extension

Tags: vscode-debugger

I have tried and tried and tried to debug the app in `VSCode` using [chrome-extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code) until i come here to ask for help. I have read the manuals how to debug etc , but i miss something .

Until now what i achieved is only to debug the React Client on `localhost:8001` with the below:

```
{
  "name": "Attach to Chrome",
  "port": 9222,
  "request": "attach",
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "urlFilter": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/*",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

I don't want it to open any new Chrome Tabs so i found out the above works after doing some work around with Chrome launching adding `--remote-debugging-port=9222`:

[image]

Now my problem is i can't debug the Node.js server which is running on port `3000`:

```
{
  "name": "Attach to Node",
  "port": 3000,
  "request": "attach",
  "type": "pwa-node"
}
```

I have tried the above it doesn't work .

I am starting my project using `$ npm start`. My project code looks like [this](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Expentour) i am using webpack-dev-server .